# Persist entity : cannot be null

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

When I use this code, I have this error " **Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'ecriture_id' cannot be null** " :

```
    $produit = new Produit();
    $ecriture = new Ecriture();
    $produit->setEcriture($ecriture);
    // $this->em->persist($ecriture);
    $this->em->persist($produit);
```

If I uncommented " ***$this->em->persist($ecriture)*** " it's work true.

I don't understand because my "Produit" entity **have a cascade persist** :

**Entity "Produit" :**

```
class Produit
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="LogicielBundle\Entity\Ecriture", inversedBy="gestionLocativeProduit", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $ecriture;

    public function setEcriture(\LogicielBundle\Entity\Ecriture $ecriture)
    {
        $ecriture->setGestionLocativeProduit($this);
        $this->ecriture = $ecriture;
        // Similar problem if I add "$ecriture->setGestionLocativeProduit($this);" right here
        return $this;
    }

    public function getEcriture()
    {
        return $this->ecriture;
    }
```

**Entity "Ecriture" :**

```
class Ecriture
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="LogicielBundle\Entity\GestionLocative\Produit", mappedBy="ecriture")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $gestionLocativeProduit;

    public function setGestionLocativeProduit(\LogicielBundle\Entity\GestionLocative\Produit $gestionLocativeProduit)
    {
        $this->gestionLocativeProduit = $gestionLocativeProduit;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getGestionLocativeProduit()
    {
        return $this->gestionLocativeProduit;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have always had similair problems when I added new columns to my database, and got liek you the cannot be null error.

What mostly fixed it for me was adding nullable is true, then in twig, controller or form add the required = true attribute. Therefor it always had to be filled.